# Why am I getting an attribute problem for the current node when this issue is addressed?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have written the following code for Linked lists to solve the problem: "Given the head of a linked list and an integer val, remove all the nodes of the linked list that has Node.val == val, and return the new head."

For example: Input: head = [1,2,6,3,4,5,6], val = 6,   Output: [1,2,3,4,5]

```
def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        curr = head
        nex = head.next


        while curr.val == val: 
            curr = nex 
            nex = nex.next

        while curr:
            if nex.val == val:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
                curr = curr.next.next
                nex = curr.next

            else:
                curr.next = nex
                curr = curr.next
                nex=nex.next
        
        return head
```

For some reason, I am getting an 'AttributeError: NoneType has no attribute 'next' for the line "curr = curr.next.next"

Now while I understand the issue, I don't see why it is coming up, because doesn't the 'while curr' line cause the while loop to break if curr = None??

Can someone please point out the error and perhaps suggest a fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You’re right that `curr` isn’t None on that line, but `curr.next` could be None, so `curr.next.next` is trying to access next from None, hence the AttributeError.

There are a couple of things you can improve with your attempt:

1. the first `while` loop tries to skip the front of the list if it equals the value, but your function returns `head`, which may have been removed.
2. in your second while loop, since your if statement is accessing `nex.val`, you should change the condition to verify that `nex` is not None.

An example fix:

```py
def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
    # corner case - list could be empty
    if head is None:
        return head

    # skip node(s) front of list if match
    newHead = head
    while newHead and newHead.val == val:
        newHead = newHead.next

    # corner case: list could be empty now
    if not newHead:
        return newHead

    curr = newHead
    nex = curr.next

    while nex:
        if nex.val == val:
            curr.next = nex.next
            nex = nex.next
        else:
            curr = nex
            nex = nex.next
        
    return newHead
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't understand the fix, what do you mean? I tried amending the code to "while curr and curr.next" but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.